# How to run python functions sequentially

Tags: python

In the code below, "list.py" will read **target_list.txt** and create a domain list as "http://testsites.com". 
Only when this process is completed, I know that **target_list** is finished, and my other function must run.  How do I sequence them properly?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Queue

targetsite = "target_list.txt"
def domaincreate(targetsitelist):
    for i in targetsite.readlines():
        i = i.strip()
        Url = "http://" + i
        DomainList = open("LiveSite.txt", "rb")
        DomainList.write(Url)
        DomainList.close()

def SiteBrowser():
    TargetSite = "LiveSite.txt"
    Tar = open(TargetSite, "rb")
    for Links in Tar.readlines():
        Links = Links.strip()
        UrlSites = "http://www." + Links
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(UrlSites)
    browser.save_screenshot(Links+".png")
    browser.quit()
domaincreate(targetsite)
SiteBrowser()
```

Comment: What is the problem with simply calling one function, then the other, in normal sequence?  What part of the above is **list.py**, and what part is the other function?

Comment: normally when i call domaincreate fun.  it must create LiveSite.txt  after then SiteBrowser fun. should work.

Comment: I *think* I understand what you want.  You haven't yet described what doesn't work in this code.

Comment: python first time calling domain create func. as well as  same time running SiteBrowser func. but while SiteBrowser func is . running, LiveSite.txt doesn't finish yet. thats why my application doesn't work.

Comment: We need more evidence of what is happening.  Please post your execution trace (you *did* trace the execution before posting here, right?).  The code you post is purely sequential; the language guarantees that the **for i** loop is complete and **LiveSite.txt** is closed before returning from the call.  Please show where there is execution overlap.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your description.  Most of all, you say "LiveSite.txt doesn't finish".  **LiveSite.txt** is a file, not an execution thread: it cannot "finish", as it does not execute.  Do you mean that it doesn't have the contents you expect?  **domaincreate** is what finishes before **SiteBrowser** begins.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that, whatever problem you have, a large part is because you are trying to write to a file that is open read-only.  If you're running on Windows, you may later have a problem that you are in binary mode, but writing a text file (under a UNIX-based system, there's no problem).